# jqgrid 3.8.2 filterToolbar - textboxes disappear when cols are reordered

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have implemented a jqgrid using the code below. The grid works fine, but when I drag and change the order of columns (reorder), the textboxes below the last column(s) disappear on each reorder.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Content("/Contacts/DynamicGridData/")',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Last Name', 'First Name', 'Country', 'Category'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'CountryId', index: 'CountryId', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'CategoryId', index: 'CategoryId', align: 'left'}],
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'LastName',
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            sortable: true,
            loadonce: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            gridview: true,
            autowidth: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            imgpath: '@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/jqgrid/smoothness/images")'
        });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', "#pager", { caption: "", title: "Toggle Search Bar", buttonicon: 'ui-icon-pin-s', onClickButton: function () { $("#list")[0].toggleToolbar() } });
    }); 
</script>

<table id="list" class="scroll"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RahulVyas.htm) my test. Which version of jQuery UI and jQuery you use?

Small remarks: The parameter `imgpath` is [deprecated](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aupgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5) since many jqGrid releases and you should remove it. In the same way the class="scroll" will also not used. So you can reduce the HTML to

```
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Comment: Oleg, Thanks for your help. I checked your test solution, try reordering the columns (by dragging the column header) and see what happens to the last text box on filterToolbar.

Comment: @Rahul Vyas: I have no problem. Which web browser you use?

Comment: @Oleg: Looks like it is a known issue: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issuesearch?state=open&q=chrome#issue/92

Comment: @Rahul Vyas: You are write it is the same bug. I could reproduce it in Chrome 10 and Safari 5 (both using Webkit engine). I find interesting that in Firefox if one drag the header of the last column, the last textbox of the searching toolbar will be not visible, but after the dropping of the column header all is OK. Probably one can use FF to localize the problem.

Comment: @Oleg: Is there any way I can drop the filterToolbar and recreate it again after a reorder takes place? Will it solve the issue? Thanks again for all your time on this issue. This has taken up many hours now for me.

Comment: To achieve what I wanted to achieve - some way to have column reorder with search toolbar, I used the columnChooser method described at link below, however the original question is still open: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser